# Rails Migration to reorder column values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a table named `gifts` which has a column `name` and the entries for the column name are as following:

1. electronics
2. apparel
3. beauty
4. others
5. food

I want to reorder the column values in a way that the entry `others` is the last entry.

Any leads on how that would be possible?

Comment: Add an integer column called `position`, set it to the order that you want, and then order the sql query by `position: :asc`

Comment: I would also check out the gem `acts_as_list`. It provides logic to make ordering records a little easier.